# Making div line up horizontally on a single row

Tags: html, css

This is driving me insane. I have something like this:

```
<div class="outer">
    <ul>

        <li>
          <div class="inner" style="width:150px; height:200px">
            <a href="#" title="@item.Title"><img src="fdfsd.jpg" /></a>
            <br />
            lorem ipsum
           </div>
        </li>

//etc (multiple li's)

</ul>

</div>
```

I want the outer div to take 100% width to fill the container, and a height of say 250px. and i want all the inner divs to line up horizontally. if they exceed the horizontal width the outer div should have horizontal scroll bars. i.e all inner divs will be on one horizontal row.

Comment: @jacktheripper, not really. I don't think i explained too well.. I got it working eventually by using white-space:nowrap; on the outer div.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're aiming to achieve
http://jsfiddle.net/Fe5Dr/